# Change several CSS based on boolean

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a page that changes based on Local time through the day.  If it's evening there is another background image, the color is different and so on. 
I did a few changes with `document.getElementById();` but this will take way too long for each element.

I was thinking, is there perhaps a short way to execute severall css code based on boolean outcome. 
I tried to look up for something like `@input css` but couldn't find more.

Edit: I actually mean "Is there perhaps a short way to CHANGE several css code from different divs and ids".
For example: The `color:` of `#message`is different based on time of the day

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Can you give an example

Comment: One option you can do here is use different classes for each mode, if there are only a few (such as morning, afternoon, and night).

Comment: Add a body class with JS if it's evening. That one change will affect as much CSS & elements as you want.

Comment: Sorry, it was bad advice, they're not useful for this.

Comment: There are only 4, night, morning, evening, afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can add different classes to your `body` element depending on what time of the day it is. You can then use those classes to style any other element on the page.

```js
const hour = new Date().getHours();

let className = 'morning';

if (hour > 21) {
  className = 'night';
} else if (hour > 18) {
  className = 'evening';
} else if (hour > 12) {
  className = 'afternoon';
}

document.body.classList.add(className);
```

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.night .bg {
  background: black;
}

.evening .bg {
  background: orange;
}

.afternoon .bg {
  background: yellow;
}

.morning .bg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used new Date(), getHours, getMinutes and getSeconds. since I also have the display the time. But what const hour and let className do here?

Comment: That's fine, you can change the calculation however you want. In my example, I use `hour` in the if statements in order to determine which CSS class I should add to the body element. I store it in the `className` variable and then use it to add it to `body`.

Comment: I Edited my question maybe that can clear things up

Comment: Yeah, I think we're talking about the same thing still. You can use the class in the body element to style anything based on the time of day.

Comment: For example, you could do ```.morning #message { color: blue; }``` to make your message element blue in the morning and maybe ```.night #message { color: white }``` to make it white during the night.